# Casting Objective C blocks in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, casting, objective-c-blocks

There is a particular case where I can't find the correct solution on how to cast a block defined in Objective C to a closure in Swift, so that I can execute it in Swift. For other cases using `@escaping` helped when having another block/closure being passed to a closure. But unfortunately not in this case.

Block type definitions in Objective C:

```
typedef void (^ViewModelUpdatedBlock)(GetValueForKeyPathBlock);
typedef id (^GetValueForKeyPathBlock)(NSString * keyPath);
```

Declaration of a block in Objective C:

```
someNSMutableDictionary[kViewModelUpdatedBlockKey] = ^(GetValueForKeyPathBlock getValueBlock) { ... }
```

When I try to use one of these blocks in Swift I can't find the correct way to cast it. I tried:

```
let viewModelUpdatedBlock = someNSMutableDictionary[kViewModelUpdatedBlockKey] as? ViewModelUpdatedBlock // = nil

let viewModelUpdatedBlock = someNSMutableDictionary[kViewModelUpdatedBlockKey] as? (GetValueForKeyPathBlock?)->() // = nil

let viewModelUpdatedBlock = someNSMutableDictionary[kViewModelUpdatedBlockKey] as? (GetValueForKeyPathBlock)->() // = nil

let viewModelUpdatedBlock = someNSMutableDictionary[kViewModelUpdatedBlockKey] as? (@escaping GetValueForKeyPathBlock)->() // = nil
```

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by ***fails***? Do you get compiler error or it's not working as expected?

Comment: @nayem the cast results in a ``nil``

Comment: Because of the way Swift functions are stored, you can't just pass them as objects to Objective-C. Either keep this code in Objective-C or use a generic wrapper class to box the function.

Comment: Thanks @matt ! Can you point me to more details about why that isn't working? Not that I don't believe you, but I just want to understand.
Can you please post your comment as answer?

Comment: How about something like `as @convention(block) (GetValueForKeyPathBlock)->()`?

Comment: Thanks @newacct , but unfortunately that doesn't work.